# How to hide the URL change when using apache rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How do I hide the URL change when using an apache rewrite? I have searched for hours on this issue and have decided to come here to find out the answer. So any help/clues would be greatly appreciated!

Right now I am using:

```
RewriteRule ^/Page/(.*)$ http://domain.com/page.cfm?pagevar=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem with that is, when you go navigate to `http://domain.com/Page/abc123`
 it works. BUT, it changes the browser url to `http://domain.com/page.cfm?pagevar=abc123`,

I want it to perform that same action, but show http://domain.com/Page/abc123 as the url.

Please, any insight on this would be very appreciated!
Thanks again.

Comment: [Don't forget to take a look on how to reward users that have helped you, improve your question when needed and other useful tips on how to best use this website.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First rule will redirect your ugly URL to the pretty URL format.

Second rule will internally redirect it back for the user will not see the ugly URL.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /page.cfm?pagevar=abc123 to /Page/abc123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+page\.cfm\?pagevar=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Page/%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally forward /Page/abc123 to /page.cfm?pagevar=abc123
RewriteRule ^Page/(.*)/?$ /page.cfm?pagevar=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The above rules are to be used on `.htaccess` files and assumes `page.cfm` is on the root of your domain folder along with the `.htaccess` file.

Like your examples proposes.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, I was considering that but that only applies if he actually want any query strings carried to the new URL format.

Comment: Yes agreed but you never know these rewrite requirements. But yes OP didn't mention about any such requirement.

Comment: @prix Thanks for such the speedy reply! As I was afraid of.. when using: `RewriteBase /` it causes the webservers to freak out when I try to run `apachectl restart`. Is it required for `RewriteRule ^Page/(.*)/?$ /page.cfm?pagevar=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` to work?

Edit: the webserver throws `RewriteBase: only valid in per-directory config files` when running `apachectl restart`.

Comment: @cEMa Like I have mentioned you don't need to place that on the virtualhost you place that on an .htaccess on the root folder of that domain.

Comment: @Prix Is there a way to accomplish this NOT using a .htaccess

Comment: Yes remove the rewritebase or place it inside a directory directive and place the `/` at the `^Page`. You can only use `RewriteBase` inside `<directory ...>` on the conf as pointed out by your error message.

Comment: @Prix Alright, I have gotten this error before, but I thought I had just used the wrong code. Using: `RewriteRule ^/Page/(.*)/?$ /page.cfm?pagevar=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` The url works, it stays the same. But the webpage looks like this: (http://postimg.org/image/l4rl1ojdv/) to much text so had to do screenshot.. Any ideas what might cause this?? Seems like it's one thing after another!

Comment: @cEMa you need to properly configure cfm to work and that is a complete different question and would go on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Prix, Thanks again for all of the continual support. It is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `http://domain.com` part of the rule's target. When you have that, it implicity redirects the browser instead of internally rewriting:

```
RewriteRule ^/Page/(.*)$ /page.cfm?pagevar=$1 [NC,L]
```