# Host multiple websites using LAMP, Virtualmin and Cloudflare on Virtual Private Server

Tags: dns, vps, webmin

Currently all my websites are on Shared Hosting. Because of slow speed I am planning to migrate them to Virtual Private Server.

My plan is to use Virtualmin on this VPS. But I am not getting any idea how to host multiple websites using virtualmin as there will be only one IP address for my VPS.

How to setup DNS records for all the websites on CloudFlare Services as all the websites will point to same IP address how do they get distinguished from each other?

Do I need to configure DNS Server on virtualmin?

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976145/secretly-do-a-mod-rewrite-on-domain-name/30992664#30992664

Comment: Thanks, but my confusion is different. I have different websites currently hosted from different hostings now I want to migrate all these to a VPS. I am confused with how to update DNS entries for all of them as they all will be pointing on same IP address.

Comment: may have linked the wrong one, although this link is in the previous: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602324/how-to-detect-an-incoming-request-with-php-script-from-a-cname-subdomain/30630937#30630937